# PowerBuilder Datawindow EditMask for IP Address

Tags: ip, powerbuilder, datawindow

Please help me for writing datawindow editmask for IP address. Currently I am doing like this
`###.###.###.###` but it can also allow `300.300.300.300`, and a valid ip address only allows maximum `255.255.255.255`. Please guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You'll have to create an user event using `pbm_keydown` or `pbm_downkey` as event id and write a script to stop keystrokes from being allowed. The return value allows you to deny that key or not.

Comment: Can't what? check input in itemchanged? OP said nothing about validating each keystroke.

Comment: You can't create a mask that also validates. Mask only formats input. You have to validate manually

Answer (score 0):

Edit masks don't validate input they just format it.  You might be better off using the itemchanged event to validate the data.

Answer (score 0):

your edit mask is okay,
If I were you, I will define 4 number column in the datawindow
howerver, if you want validation, you need to code in itemchanged event:

```
ls_colname = dw_1.GetcolumnName()
Choose Case ls_colname

    Case "subnet_msk_1"
        if Integer(dw_1.getText()) > 255
          MessageBox("Warning", "Incorrect Input, subnet mask value should not be > 255")
          /*this will not let the datawindow accept the invalid input*/
          return 1
        end if
    Case "subnet_msk_2"
         /*do the same*/
    Case "subnet_msk_3"
         /*do the same*/
    Case "subnet_msk_4"
         /*do the same*/
    /*write your logic here*/
End Choose
```

If you want to use only 1 String cloumn, I believe that you will need to use the mid() function, just press F1 in PB, you can find out the examples, in your case:

```
ls_colname = dw_1.GetcolumnName()
Choose Case ls_colname

    Case "subnet_msk"
     if Mid(dw_1.getText(), 1, 4) > 255 OR Mid(dw_1.getText(), 4, 8) > 255 /*etc..*/
         /*your logic here*/
     end if
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Match function to validate ip address after user's input:

```
int i, j
int matchedCount
boolean isValid

String patterns[] = {"^25[0-5]$", "^2[0-4][0-9]$", "^[01]?[0-9][0-9]?$"}
string ip[] = {"162","168","1","1"} // test for success
//string ip[] = {"162","168","256","101"} // test for fail

for i = 1 to 4
    for j = 1 to 3
        if match(ip[i], patterns[j]) then matchedCount++
    next
next

isValid = (matchedCount = 4)
```

Not optimized, but compact